# Drupal - Where is located config.js of CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, drupal-8

I am trying to find the configuration file of CKEditor (v8.5.3) so I can remove automatical stripping of classes from div element using `config.extraAllowedContent = 'div(*)';`

I have found some threads where are people referencing the config.js in the root file of CKEditor but I cant find it in there. Any idea where I can found this configuration file?
Thank you for response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Drupal guy but from what I have checked, in D8 you can set the configuration using `hook_editor_js_settings_alter`. Please see:

- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21editor%21editor.api.php/function/hook_editor_js_settings_alter/8.5.x
- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186102/drupal-8-ckeditor-behaves-ltr-in-an-rtl-site/186303#186303

When it comes to filtering HTML however you should, in your Drupal Admin Panel, go to `Configuration -> Content Authoring (Text formats and editors)`. There you can either configure "Allowed HTML tags" or simply uncheck "Limit allowed HTML tags and correct faulty HTML" checkbox what will allow everything.

If you wish to configure your HTML here is IMO a nice link showing the filter syntax: https://www.drupal.org/node/2571349

Answer (score 0):

I've ran a file search from the command line, and can confirm that nowhere does the file config.js exist (using v8.6.x).

I found another case of an admin losing classes on DIVs in CKEditor (though in version 8.2.x), and the only way she found to remedy that, was to create a new text format at **/admin/config/content/formats**. Then, including  in allowed HTML tags:

```
<div class>
```

Her full solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050090/drupal-8-2-x-text-editor-stripping-removing-div-classes%22here%22). It includes some pointers as to which options to select when creating the new text format.